# Snowflake Data Sharing - Any way to grant user specific access?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We're looking to share data with departments that share a single Snowflake account, but need differential access to our data.

From the Snowflake documentation, it looks like sharing is always at the account level. Is there any way user or role level access can be controlled from the data provider side, or does this require the data consumer to do the appropriate grants?

Update: We're using secure data sharing to share data between accounts. We want to be able to restrict access to certain users or roles on the other account, if possible.

Comment: Sharing data to another account allows that account to use that data as if they had the object locally in their instance. What they do with it is up to them and you have no control, as the sharer, over that. You can only create and drop the share.

Answer (score 2):

The snowflake access is actually role-level, there's no account-level access. The roles are set in a hierarchy and you can use that to customize your access quite extensively. Please take a while to read about the best practices before setting up the roles:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-considerations.html

edit: and for secure data sharing you're most likely looking at https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-config.html

Comment: To clarify, this is about account to account sharing. I've updated the question.

Comment: hm, managed accounts then? (as in https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-create.html) - these are reader-only "internal" accounts which isn't the same as Snowflake accounts, so I guess you can consider them users....

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-config.html has a description on how to do the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You can't restrict access to users or roles on the other account from the provider account.

You can only control the object access to the share like granting/revoking select access on tables and secured views in the provider account.

Reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-gs