# Snowflake - Grant permissions by username

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-administration, database-permissions

I'm trying to restrict read permissions on some entities to a specific user.

In Oracle I'd simply do

```
GRANT SELECT ON sensitive_schema.my_table1 TO error_2646;
GRANT SELECT ON sensitive_schema.my_table2 TO error_2646;
GRANT SELECT ON sensitive_schema.my_tableN TO error_2646;
```

or ideally at schema level

```
GRANT SELECT ON sensitive_schema TO error_2646;
```

Can I do this in Snowflake? In the documentation it looks like permissions are managed by role in Snowflake and I'd rather not change this person's role.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html

Comment: Sifted through the recommendations more. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621280/snowflake-data-sharing-any-way-to-grant-user-specific-access But not exact as "error_2646" is not a shared account in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Snowflake's approch for permission is **Role-based Access Control (RBAC)** you will not be able to give GRANTS to a specific user.

If you absolutly don't want to work on role for this, maybe you can have a look on [Dynamic Data Masking](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-column-ddm-use.html). You will be able to mask data to a specific user using `current_user()`. But you will have to create a masking policy for every field type you want to mask and apply this policy to every field in your table so i would not recommend this compared to role approach.

Comment: Appreciate it. I was figuring so by the documentation but good to have the confirmation that I didn't miss something.